# how to add inputs to this piece of code?

Tags: python

If I use the following code introducing the parameters manually, it works:

```
def evaluatePoly(poly, x):
    result = 0
    for i in range(len(poly)):
        result += poly[i] * x ** i
    return float(result)

>>> evaluatePoly([1,2,2],2)
13
```

I would like to be asked to introduce only the coefficients, without brackets, and the value where I want to evaluate my polynomial equation. Something like this:

```
poly=(raw_input('Enter a list of coefficients from your polynomial equation: '))
x=int(raw_input('Enter the value where you want to evaluate your polynomial equation: '))

print(evaluatePoly(poly, x))
```

But if I try that, Python gives me this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
```

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: `raw_input` returns a string, so your list input is not going to work.

Comment: Depending on how you expect the list of coefficients to be inserted (as csv or w/e), it's a matter of string processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`raw_input` will return a string. You can process a string into a list of values like so:

```
coeffs = raw_input('Enter a list of coefficients from your polynomial equation: ') # is a String
poly = coeffs.split() # split the string based on whitespace
poly = map(int, poly) # Convert each element to integer using int(...)
```

If you want to accept floats, use `float` instead of `int`, and if you want to split on comma, use `coeffs.split(",")` instead of `coeffs.split()`.

### example

```
>>> x=int(raw_input('Enter the value where you want to evaluate your polynomial equation: '))
Enter the value where you want to evaluate your polynomial equation: 2
>>> coeffs = raw_input('Enter a list of coefficients from your polynomial equation: ')
Enter a list of coefficients from your polynomial equation: 3 2 5
>>> poly = coeffs.split()
>>> poly = map(int, poly)
>>> print(evaluatePoly(poly, x))
27.0
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

evaluate your `input()` list with `eval()`, converting from string to list. Your evaluation can be inside function body. I did so in these lines

```
def evaluatePoly(poly, x):
    result = 0
    poly=eval(poly)
    for i in range(len(poly)):
        result += poly[i] * x ** i
    return float(result)

poly=(input('Enter a list of coefficients from your polynomial equation: '))
x=int(input('Enter the value where you want to evaluate your polynomial equation: '))

print(str(evaluatePoly(poly, x)))
```

and i get

```
>>> 
Enter a list of coefficients from your polynomial equation: [1,2]
Enter the value where you want to evaluate your polynomial equation: 5
11.0
```

please note that using `eval()` may be a risk for your program.